# One of my Entities is not a proxy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The error I am receiving-

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The value "PHSRP_Dashboard.WorkSessionBreak"
>   is not of type
>   "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.WorkSessionBreak_06908<..many
>   characters..>6E3E" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

only occurs when a new WorkSessionBreak record has been added to the database. It does not occur for records that have only been modified, nor will it re-occur when the program is restarted and the (not so) new record is revisited.

```
private void Edit_WorkSessionBreak_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedWorkSessionID >= 0)
    {
        var BreakSet = editEmployee.EmployeeWorkSessions
                                   .SelectMany(ws => ws.WorkSessionBreaks)
                                   .Where(b => b.DELETED != true && b.EmployeeWorkSessionID == SelectedWorkSessionID);

        if (BreakSet.Any())
        {
            var BreakSetSorted = BreakSet.OrderBy(b => b.OutTime);
            this.bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.DataSource = BreakSetSorted;        //  Blows-up on New record added.
        }
        else
        {
            this.bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.DataSource = new BindingList<WorkSessionBreak>();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.DataSource = new BindingList<WorkSessionBreak>();
    }

    if (bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.Count > 0)
    {
        if (syncToViewBreak(((WorkSessionBreak)bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.Current).WorkSessionBreakID))
        {
            SelectedWorkSessionBreakID = ((WorkSessionBreak)bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.Current).WorkSessionBreakID;
        }
    }

    bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.ResetBindings(false); 
}
```

The Dialog form we returned from is working correctly.  The changes/additions have been correctly placed in the database, but the BindingSources associated with this Parent form are not automatically reordering.

An examination of the variable contents in the debugger shows that the New record in the Enumerable returned by LINQ is a WorkSessionBreak while the other pre-existing items are WorkSessionBreak ***Proxies***.

[Debugger View 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XniXb.png)

The Sorting works but also returns a mix of Types and Proxies:

[Debugger View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz7YA.png)

The next instruction crashes because one item is not the same type (i.e. Proxy) as the others.

[Debugger View 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ICV.png)

I have no idea what to do about this or why it is occurring.  This algorithm is used in other parts of this same form without this error occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is what is known as [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution). Basically, the code is attempting to add items to a database query.

Here:

```
var BreakSet = editEmployee.EmployeeWorkSessions
    .SelectMany(ws => ws.WorkSessionBreaks)
    .Where(b => b.DELETED != true 
             && b.EmployeeWorkSessionID == SelectedWorkSessionID);
```

`BreakSet` is an `IQueryable<WorkSessionBreak>`. Whenever you see an `IQueryable<SomeClass>`, remember that it represents a query and (normally) not data you have in memory.

```
var BreakSet = editEmployee.EmployeeWorkSessions
   .SelectMany(ws => ws.WorkSessionBreaks)
   .Where(b => b.DELETED != true 
            && b.EmployeeWorkSessionID == SelectedWorkSessionID)
   .OrderBy(b => b.OutTime)
   .ToList();

if (BreakSet.Any())
{
    this.bs_WorkSessionBreaks_Display.DataSource = BreakSet;
}
```

With this, you now have a single database call. The `OrderBy` clause doesn't affect the results of a `COUNT` query, so you can make it as part of the initial query. Notice that the `ToList()` call at the end is what executes the query so the results are materialized.